Getting html content displayed when launched jupyterlab from anaconda navigator
I am getting below html content displayed on notepad when launched jupyterlab from anaconda navigator.
<!DOCTYPE html>



    
    
    Opening Jupyter Application



<p>
    This page should redirect you to a Jupyter application. If it doesn't,
    <a href="http://localhost:8889/lab?``your text``token=a4cdeb87c4e796c201be701030271f26f96a4f13767e58d5">click here to go to Jupyter</a>.
</p>

can someone please suggest what is wrong here?
I tried to find solutions on google with no luck
I am expecting to launch jupyterlab from anaconda navigator

This question is not posted correctly I am getting below html content on launch on jupyterlab





Opening Jupyter Application



    This page should redirect you to a Jupyter application. If it doesn't,
    click here to go to Jupyter.



If you post HTML, you need to handle it as code. I restored your original attempt, but it's not the same you posted into comments. Please fix it using the [edit] link if needed and delete the comment

As to the issue, you seem to have Notepad set to open if you click on HTML code in your system. You need to reset so a browser opens your .html files by default.  Here covers how to fix that by setting the default application for handling .html files.

Here covers how to fix that by setting the default application to your browser for handling .html files.
